# Can i find more Information like the row in a Error

Tags: android-studio, error-handling

i dont find the problem can i see in the error where it is or can i find near information and not only `Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String`

```
3485-3485/com.example.tobias.uebung1 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.tobias.uebung1, PID: 3485
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tobias.uebung1/com.example.tobias.uebung1.main}: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
            at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.getString(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:225)
            at com.example.tobias.uebung1.main.Main(main.java:440)
            at com.example.tobias.uebung1.main.onCreate(main.java:106)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Do you need to be pointed to this line? `at com.example.tobias.uebung1.main.Main(main.java:440)`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how are we supposed to help, but I think the best thing you can do now is to add some breakpoints and debug it. Or you can post the code so we can help.